# How to get parameter from navigateByUrl?

Tags: angular, angular8

I do navigation using:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(item.url);
```

Where `item.url` has value:

```
orgtree/1
```

Route is:

```
{
        path: "orgtree/:orgstructure",
        component: OrganizationsComponent
      }
```

Inside component I do:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);

    });
}
```

Why I get empty params?

Also I have tried this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/orgtree', 1]);
```

NO EFFECT

**I got problem:**

Route should be:

```
{
        path: "orgtree",
        component: OrganizationsComponent
      }
```

Comment: Please show your _whole_ component. Is it decorated with `implements OnInit` for example? Missing some import? What is `route`, actually (is it an `ActivatedRoute` or `Router` or what?)

Comment: all are present, I have checked

Comment: What is `this.route` in your `constructor()`?

Comment: this:     private route: ActivatedRoute

Comment: I debug route I see this: '/orgtree?orgstructure=OrgStructure1')

Comment: reason: "Navigation ID 3 is not equal to the current navigation id 4"}
id: 3
reason: "Navigation ID 3 is not equal to the current navigation id 4"
url: "/orgtree?orgstructure=OrgStructure1"
__proto__: RouterEvent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should declare your variables and then use it:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe( params => {
    this.orgstructure = params.get('orgstructure');    
  });
}
```

UPDATE:

You should declare your parameters like that:

```
this.router.navigate(['/orgtree'], {queryParams: {orgstructure: 1}});
```

OR if you want to use `navigateByUrl` method:

```
const url = '/probarborrar?id=33';
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
```

[Please, see work demo at stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3fkg6e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent-a.component.ts)

Comment: Inside constructor or nginit?

Comment: @OPV you can declare in constructor or in `ngOnInit`.

Comment: I have completed url like; /orgtree/1

Comment: @Opv Have you written code like that `this.router.navigate(['/orgtree'], {queryParams: {orgstructure: 1}});` and params are not got? If yes, could you show your `import` statements and declaration of `route` variable?

Comment: import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

Comment: @OPV please, [see work demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytfgp8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent-b.component.ts)

Comment: Why `queryParams`? OP wants a path parameter and implements `navigateByUrl()`. Maybe they get the URI from a database or something as a premade string.

Comment: I get this debug info: `NavigationCancel {id: 3, url: "/orgtree?orgstructure=OrgStructure1", reason: "Navigation ID 3 is not equal to the current navigation id 4"}
id: 3
reason: "Navigation ID 3 is not equal to the current navigation id 4"
url: "/orgtree?orgstructure=OrgStructure1"
__proto__: RouterEvent`

Comment: @msanford OP said `Also I have tried this: this.router.navigate(['/orgtree', 1]);`. However, I've added [stackblitz example where `navigateByUrl` is implemented](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3fkg6e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent-a.component.ts)

Comment: @OPV it is really hard to debug without your code. Could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example?

Comment: @OPV maybe you are calling `router.navigate` twice?

Answer (score 3):

```ts
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       console.log(param);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Try this code, make sure `route` is an instance of `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: empty object it returns

Comment: It would be easy to help if you share your code snippet on slackblitz

Comment: I think it's empty because you are using params inside subscribe however you are logging param which does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Refer [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwf7w4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fa%2Fa.component.ts) link, I reproduced your scenario in Stackblitz

a.component.html

```
<button (click)="navTo()">nav to b</button>
```

a.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.css']
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(    private router: Router
) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  navTo() {
    let item = {
      url : `b/${Math.random()}`
    };
    this.router.navigateByUrl(item.url);
  }

}
```

b.component.html

```
<h1>Value in param : {{value}}</h1>

<button routerLink="/a">back to a</button>
```

b.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./b.component.css']
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {
  public value;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.value = this.route.snapshot.params.id; 
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
  }

}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AComponent } from './a/a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b/b.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'b/:id',
    component: BComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params.get('orgstructure'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the params by its name
params.get("orgstructure")

Answer (score 0):

Suppose:

```
const url = '/some-url';
```

In some scenarios, this will work:

```
window.location.href = url;
```

instead of

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
```

This is due to the way routing is designed in angular.